# WebKit how to handle an exception

Tags: webkit

Hey, I'm using a ScriptDebugDelegate to notify me when an exception occurs in the exceptionWasRaised function.

However, I'd like to know how I could ignore the exception, ie. just skip the line of code that'd normally fire an exception.

Thanks
ASH

Answer (score 1):

If you know the line where the exception occurs you could use a try/catch with no code inside the catch block

```
@try {
    //my code that throws exception
} @catch ( NSException *e ) {
}
```

You can even filter it by using a specific exception type that you want like for CustomException:

```
@try {
    //my code that throws exception
} @catch ( MyCustomException *e ) {
}
```

What will cause any `MyCustomException` to be ignored, and all other to be fired.

NOTE: It is important to use that only for testing and debugging proposes as empty catches are always wrong.